# run robocopy bat to copy entire drive to another drive

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, cmd, robocopy

I'm trying to run a simple backup (mirror) of one entire drive (d:) to another drive (k:). I've created a .bat file ('backup.bat') defining the source (d:) and destination (k:) and placed this batch file within a folder on the d drive (d:\temp). When I double-click on the batch file it defines the source as d:\temp, instead of what I've defined it as in the batch file; d:.

Here is the text in the .bat file:

```
@echo off
echo To begin backing up data:
pause
robocopy "D:" "K:" /L /v                 
echo.
pause
exit
```

And this is what shows up when I double-click on the backup.bat

[image]

As you can see, source is defined as d:\temp. This is where the batch file is located, but in the batch file I defined it as D:. For some reason, the destination is defined correctly.

Any ideas?

-al

EDIT: If I add the '/' to the source and destination location, see code below, I see even more odd behavior (see screenshot). The source is now both the defined source and destination combined, w/ no destination.

```
@echo off

echo To begin backing up data:
pause

robocopy "D:\" "K:\" /L /v


echo.            
pause
exit
```

[image]

And, if I remove the "" from the source and destination....IT WORKs!

```
@echo off

echo To begin backing up data:
pause

robocopy D:\ K:\ /L /v
echo.            
pause
exit
```

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

with `"D:"` you are **not** specifying the *root* directory of the D drive (`D:\`) but the *current* directory of D instead, (`D:\temp` in your example).

To solve this problem, just add `\` to the source spec (and while there, to the dest spec as well)

```
robocopy d:\ k:\ /L /v
```

Comment: I've tried that and it produces something even more odd. See my edits above.

Comment: @ PA. was correct, I not only needed to add the \, I also needed to remove the quotes. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `/E` Option.
Also check other necessary/useful params like `/copyall` `/ZB` or `/DCOPY:DAT` via `/?`.

Answer (score 1):

/L options make a dry run, nothing actually copied.

From MS website:
/l  Specifies that files are to be listed only (and not copied, deleted, or time stamped).

here is sample of my test dry run before copying and entire disk:

```
      Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras                                                                                                                                                                                                             Dirs :     63346     63346         2         0         0         0                                                                                                                                                                                                            Files :    719564    719564         0         0         0         0                                                                                                                                                                                                            Bytes :   4.039 t   4.039 t         0         0         0         0                                                                                                                                                                                                            Times :   0:27:58   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:27:57                                                                                                                                                                                                            Ended : Monday, September 6, 2021 9:25:35 AM
```

and here is my Notepad for making my command, (notice I simply remove the /L to actually copy):

for testing (dry run):
robocopy Q: G: /L /E /COPYALL /R:20 /W:15 /MT /NP /A-:SH /Z /V /TEE /LOG+:VMRobCp.log

Real run:
robocopy Q: G: /E /COPYALL /R:20 /W:15 /MT /NP /A-:SH /Z /V /TEE /LOG+:VMRobCp.log

Answer (score 0):

I have found that you need a space after the last slash when you put a path In quotes for the source and or destination.  If you have embedded spaces, you need quotes, thus you need the space after the last slash in the path, e.g. “c:\ “ not “c:\”

Can’t really tell you what’s going on there with robocopy, but all my backup scripts take this into account.

Good luck!

Comment: Fwiw, I recalled the reason for using a space following an ending slash, when within a quote.  It seems that if you leave out the space, robocopy doesn’t see that there is a path that ends in a slash, and so assumes that you entered a file name.

Comment: Why not just use the /MIR?